# "ng generate component" generates files with row of numbers

Tags: angular, angular6

I'm new to angular. I try to generate a new component under a specific folder of a project.

```
/src/app/my-shared-components
```

I run the following command under this folder:

```
ng generate component my-new-component
```

The command generates a folder of .html, .scss, .ts and .spec.ts under my-new-component folder with no problem, but the problem is, all of these files include a long row of  numbers like this:

60,112,62,10,32,32,116,97,98,108,101,45,101,118,101,110,116,45,114,97,99,101,115,32,119,111,114,107,115,33,10,60,47,112,62,10

I tested in many IDEs, branches.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It will be better if you share screenshot about issue.

Comment: make sure your angular CLI is up to date. have you tried to uninstall the CLI and then reinstall it?

Comment: interesting, any screenshot?

Comment: pics or it didn't happen

Comment: Those are [ASCII bytes](http://www.asciitable.com/) for: `<p>
  table-event-races works!
</p>`, FYI.

Comment: @KirkLarkin Thank you....do you have a suggestion on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I can't think of anything right now. It could be a display issue or it could be the file itself. Can you provide a link to the raw .html file from your example so I can check the file itself?

Comment: which editor you're using? is it supports TypeScript?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should check angular/cli, npm and nodeJS versions? It may be a compatibility issue between those three.

I had the same problem because my nodeJS version was a bit old, upgrading from 6.11.1 to 8.12.0 (for LTS, I guess 10.0.0 and above would work as well) solved the problem.

As pointed by Kirk Larkin it seems to have transformed the content of your files to ASCII, therefore you should be able to easily turn it back to TypeScript with an online converter. Make sure your app.module.ts is back to normal before trying generating another component.

I hope my input was helpful!
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

CatKanda should be marked as the correct answer.

A little more background to what causes the error. Angular cli to generate component was working fine until I updated my npm to latest version. After doing that the error mentioned above started producing this same exact error.

Upgrade your node to 10+ and it should resolve.